# What is the main and tail rotor speed (RPM) for a Sikorsky S52?

Tags: helicopter, tail-rotor

I need the RPMs for the main and tail rotor of a Sikorsky S52 for the research I am doing for my degree. I tried checking flight manuals and other websites, but I don't find concrete numbers, only percentage values.

Comment: It's variable depending on engine speed... Do you want the range? Should be easy to figure out if you have the gearbox ratios.

Comment: I can't find anything after a quick google,  but if you reached out to a museum with your question you may be able get a good answer, old guys like to talk about stuff like this, just a matter of getting the right person.

Answer (score 3):

Given the $5m$ main rotor radius and the typical blade's tip speed due to the rotation around the hub of some $200m/s$, this gives:

$ \omega =  v_{tip} / r = 200/5 = 40 [rad/s] = 380rpm $

For the tail rotor this is proportionally bigger and equals $1900rpm$.

It could be that due to the technological limitations of those times, the $\omega$ was actually a bit lower but in absence of concrete numbers, these should be reasonable values to start with.

Comment: Wikipedia states the max speed as 180 km/h, which should be included in the tip speed calculation.

Comment: The OP asks for a definit source, not an assumption

Comment: I updated the answer with the previous comments